# How can I increase gunicorn --limit-request-line in a python App Engine application with Flask?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, gunicorn

It is a sort question, I am building a very simple API with python runtime and Flask in Google Cloud Platform. Problem is that the request URL can get a bit long (approx 6000 bytes) and the current gunicorn limit is 4096. I know it will sound dumb, but I am trying to change it on the app.yaml file and when I run it it returns 500 server error. I am almost certain it is a problem in the entrypoint that I added because I do not know how to modify the app.yaml (I am new in web development). My app.yaml is as follows:

```
runtime: python37
service: py
entrypoint: gunicorn --limit-request-line 8190 main:app
```

Could someone help me if you know what error I have? I have checked GCP documentation and demos but as usual they are not very descriptive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to have gunicorn in your `requirements.txt` if you don't have it already, as the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#application_startup) mention.

Regarding the entrypoint in your `app.yaml` it looks correct, however I think you're missing adding the port to have App Engine listening to 8080, which is a requirement.

`entrypoint: gunicorn -b :8080 --limit-request-line 8190 main:app`

More information can be found as well in the following [section of the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#application_startup).

Comment: You are a savior! I added gunicorn to the requirements.txt and the port. Thank you very much again!

Comment: No problem, happy to help!
PS: Please consider marking the answer as correct so other members of the community can benefit of it :)